# Does changing an already pushed list(on a vector) change the list that is on a vector?

Tags: c++, list, vector

For example, we have a Vector of lists. And we push a list i on a vector[0] in a for loop. Then as the loop iterates, we move on to vector[1] and assign new values to list i, which will then be pushed on to vector[1]. will the list i that was pushed on vector[0] also change? Thank you.

Comment: You should add a code sample so we can clearly understand what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, unless you have a vector of `std::reference_wrapper<std::list>`, i.e. a [reference wrapper](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) around the `std::list`. `push_back` copies the value (or moves a rvalue). Note that you cannot have a container of plain references, that's why you need `std::reference_wrapper` in case you want to "emulate" push-ing back references into the container.

Code example below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
void display(T const& container)
{
    for (auto && elem : container)
    {
        for (auto && i : elem)
        {
            std::cout << i << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

template<typename T>
void display_ref(T const& container)
{
    for (auto && elem : container)
    {
        for (auto && i : elem.get())
        {
            std::cout << i << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::list<int>> v1;
    std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<std::list<int>>> v2;

    std::list<int> l{1, 2, 3};

    v1.push_back(l);
    v2.push_back(l);

    // modify l
    l.front() = 42;

    // display
    display(v1); // unchanged
    display_ref(v2); // changed
}
```

<kbd>[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6c425e4888f3f30d)</kbd>

Comment: perfect answer; makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

A [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) keeps a copy of what you assign to its elements. Therefore the list in `vector[0]` will not change when you put new values into the external list that you originally assigned to the vector.